# Way to see the method execution using JMC

Tags: java, jvm, jmc

I have been running Java flight recorder in JMC and trying to determine which method has the low performance. I look under method profile and see list of methods with count and percentage. Is there a way to see execution time of the method?

Or are there other tools that I can use to infer the execution time of each method along with load.

Comment: https://github.com/async-profiler/async-profiler/ is pretty good at this. You can also use in the "Wall-clock" mode: https://github.com/async-profiler/async-profiler/#wall-clock-profiling